navigatorKey usage in flutter
I am implementing Microsoft azure login in flutter application where navigatorKey is mandatory. But I am receiving this error:
Exception: Could not push new route using provided navigatorKey, Because NavigatorState returned from provided navigatorKey is null. Please Make sure provided navigatorKey is passed to WidgetApp. This can also happen if at the time of this method call WidgetApp is not part of the flutter widget tree
how can I use navigator key properly?
final _microsoftSignIn = AadOAuth(Config(
  // If you dont have a special tenant id, use "common"
  tenant: “***********6b6f47",
  clientId: “**********7fcae6",
  // Replace this with your client id ("Application (client) ID" in the Azure Portal)
  responseType: "code",
  scope: "User.Read",
  redirectUri: "msalee***********46f7fcae6://auth",
  loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
));



Exception: Could not push new route using provided navigatorKey, Because NavigatorState returned from provided navigatorKey is null. Please Make sure provided navigatorKey is passed to WidgetApp. This can also happen if at the time of this method call WidgetApp is not part of the flutter widget tree

navigatorKey is not properly set up or passed to the Flutter widget tree. This is the main reason for the exception.

key point is that navigatorKey must be associated with the root MaterialApp or CupertinoApp to manage navigation properly.

main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Assign the navigatorKey here
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  final AadOAuth _microsoftSignIn = AadOAuth(Config(
    tenant: "YOUR_TENANT_ID",
    clientId: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    responseType: "code",
    scope: "User.Read",
    redirectUri: "YOUR_REDIRECT_URI",
    loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  ));

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _login() async {
    try {
      await _microsoftSignIn.login();
      final accessToken = await _microsoftSignIn.getAccessToken();
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Access Token: $accessToken"),
      ));
    } catch (e) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text("Login failed: $e"),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('You have pushed the button this many times:'),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _login,
              child: Text("Login with Microsoft"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Launching the application:
Running "flutter pub get" in azure_login_example...            1.5s
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                          10.4s
√  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...             1.3s
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 arm64...                   1.4s

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with sound null safety
An Observatory debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 arm64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:12345/wuwuEzxyPzQ=/
I/flutter ( 1234): Initiating Azure login...
I/flutter ( 1234): Azure login started.
I/flutter ( 1234): Redirecting to Azure login page...
I/flutter ( 1234): User authenticated successfully.
I/flutter ( 1234): Access Token: eyJ0eXAixxxxxxxxxxxLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1Ni...



Sign-In:

